# Issue with editing the value of an item in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify an item's value in a SharePoint list with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128376/how-to-modify-an-items-value-in-a-sharepoint-list-with-powershell)

how to edit the value of a item in Sharepoint Itemlist?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$webURL = "http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp"
$listName = "OsEM1" 
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL 
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$items = $list.items 
Foreach($item in $items)
{ 
 if($item["Item"] -eq $null)
  { 
   $item["Title"] = "My first edited item!" 
   $item.Update()
  }
}
```

it says exception calling Update with 0 argument
I nearly copied the orignal code from internet, how can that be, someone can help me?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles.

Comment: Like something that actually describes your problem. Read: "Not 'rookie 2nd Q on powershell'".

Comment: thanks~ do you have any solutions about that issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `$item.Update` without the parens, PowerShell should list the method signatures which will give you an idea on what parameter(s) the method requires.